# How can I reduce range hood duct size for best performance?

Tags: hvac, ducts, range-hood

I currently have a range that was hacked in terribly by a previous contractor with flex pipe. I want to replace it with rigid duct to make it quieter and increase performance too hopefully.

The range has a 7" circular output. Right now it uses a reducer immediately from the output of the range from 6" (with a 1" gap covered with foil tape) to 4" flex and then up through a cabinet and then 90 degrees out to the side of the wall - approximately a 5 foot run. It properly should have a 7" to 4" reducer so there is no gap. I actually only see a 7" to 6" at the local store so I'd probably have to put that with the existing 6" to 4" to eliminate the gap.

I notice a lot of back draft coming out from the range fans. It does suck air but there is also back flow blowing out from the range. This is from the large reduction I'm assuming.

To make matters worse the rigid run out to the wall needs to jog over to the wall opening a good foot or so. Now it's flex tubing so that's not a problem, however I imagine if I go rigid duct, I'll need a pair of 90 deg turns potentially to make it over to the wall opening.

#### Questions:

1. Would there be less back draft and better performance if all the ducting was 7" until it goes out to the wall and have the reduction to 4" there?
2. Would it help even if it was 7" through the cabinet before the 90 degree turn, or will it make no difference in performance where the reduction occurs?
3. I'm wondering if using a small amount of flex at the end would be OK?
4. A small amount of flex is better than all flex?

Attached is a SketchUp pic of the current situation.

[image: range duct]

Comment: Each elbow increases resistance, so straighter is better(within reason).  45s are better than 90s.  7 to 4 inch might be a problem also.  It will depend on what the hood requires.  7 inch seems odd size if you only need 4 inch.  A mix of flex/rigid should not matter much.  Flex will make more gentle curves.

Comment: @crip659 well the hood requires/wants 7" the entire way, but b/c of the clearance to the roof the contractor would not put in larger than a 4" hole in the wall. That's why I'm wondering if if makes any difference where the reduction occurs. Immediately out of the range in the cabinet? Or right before the wall exhaust, so that the bulk of the ducting with be 7" instead of 4"?

Comment: Elbows plus the reduction makes the fans work much harder.  I think the reduction at the end is better(but not sure).  The reason for the four inch limit might be important.  A limit because that is the biggest that can safety be made in a support member is good, because that was the biggest hole saw they had, not so good.

Comment: @crip649 Thx for your feedback. The reduction at the end seems better to me also, however then I think of the analogy of water through a hose and it seems to suggest it doesn't really matter where the reduction occurs, the net reduction in flow will be the same. With the reduction at the end, the fan might start off with less back pressure as it fills the whole 7" duct, but when it hits that end reducer it's gonna be the same back pressure I think.

Comment: "Is this worth it?" can only be determined by you. Nobody else can determine whether the expense will be "worth" it you vs the time & money expenditure.

Comment: @FreeMan Mainly, I was wondering if there be any significant increase in CFM/performance by having the reduction happen at the end of the run before the wall. The more I think about it, I don't think there would be any difference. However, I think the flex might be worth replacing simply because it does have poor performance overall.

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit and retracted the VtC. However, you're still asking quite a few questions all in one, which doesn't work well here. Please take the [tour], then read up on [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), then maybe [edit] again to refine this down to one good question that gets to the point of what you _really_ want to know. After that, feel free to [ask a whole new question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about a different part of the project.

Comment: @FreeMan Thx for cleaning up the questions. I assume you're a mod? If you think I should post a new question for better feedback/replies I can do that, I would just ask question #2. I was also considering posting in a physics sub since it's essentially a fluid dynamics problem.

Comment: @FreeMan I've been reading on Bernoulli's equation and I'm thinking reducing farther away from the range output itself might see some performance improvements. Since when the reduction occurs, there is a turbulence and negative work being put against the direction of flow as the fluid increases in velocity at the reduction. If this happens farther away from the fan perhaps less "leakage" in the form of back draft would occur.

Comment: We're all "mods" with varying [privileges](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). Take the [tour] and read through the [help] for more on how that works. If you [edit] to focus this on one specific thing, that will help, by all means feel free to [ask a whole new question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for one of the others. If you post on [physics.se], be sure to read their help to ensure your question is on-topic. Also: ask about a flow reduction through a pipe, not about a kitchen vent. As soon as you say "kitchen", they'll want to move the question here! :)